# How to conditionally hide an object in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that look like this.

Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/qBEabad) just in case.

```
  myArray = [
     {text: 'person', role: 'person'},
     {text: 'hobby', role: 'hobbies'},
     {text:'food', role: 'foods'},
     {text:'cars', role: 'vehicles'}
  ]
```

How can i make it so that if a certain condition is false, the object with cars will be hidden and if it is true then return the array as it is?

Comment: `if (condition) myArray = [/*something else*/];`?

Comment: Is ther another or dynamic way of doing this? what if my array is really long and i want to do it in just one place without having to declare this all over the place?

Comment: Declare the parts that you want in both places in one array and the parts that you want only in one place in another array, then merge (`.concat()`) them in the place where you want both parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  myArray = [
     {text: 'person', role: 'person'},
     {text: 'hobby', role: 'hobbies'},
     {text:'food', role: 'foods'},
     {text:'cars', role: 'vehicles'}
  ]
  if(condition){
    return myArray.filter( item => item.text !== 'cars')
  }else{
    return myArray;
  }
```

Comment: *"if it is true then return the array as it is"* - I believe your logic is reversed.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter function :

```
if(condition===false) {
  myArray = myArray.filter(o=>o.text!=="cars");
}
```